# CASE WHEN on a passed in variable

Tags: java, postgresql, case

I'm using Java 11 and Postgres 9.6. I am writing a SQL query that will be included in my Java application and I will pass in values to the variables designated with a:

SQL

```sql
CASE
 WHEN (:designatorInclude IS NOT NULL)
  THEN totdl.designator_id IN (:designatorInclude)
   ELSE ttl.product_code IS NOT NULL
END
```

Java

```java
String filterProductCodes = IOUtil.readResourceText(MyService.class, "sql_files/FilterProductCodes.sql");
Query filterProductCodesQuery = this.em.createNativeQuery(filterProductCodes)

if(inDto.getIdList() != null)
{
    filterProductCodesQuery.setParameter("designatorInclude", inDto.getIdList);
}else{
    filterProductCodesQuery.setParameter("designatorInclude", null);
}
```

Passing variables in like this works in many other places in the application.  The difference here is that I'm using a CASE/WHERE statement.

Everything compiles fine, but when I try to hit this part of the code, I get the following error:

> PSQLException: ERROR: argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type record

I found 1 post on the internet about this and it did not apply to my situation.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Full SQL - case statement is towards the end.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ttl.product_code,
                    si.condition,
                    totdl.designator_id,
                    ttl.active     as ttl_active,
                    l.active       as l_active,
                    ii.mls_order_id,
                    ii.damaged,
                    ttl.id         as ttl_id,
                    ll.location_id as ll_locationId,
                    cl.location_id as cl_locationId
    FROM serial_item si
             JOIN inventory_item ii ON ii.id = si.id
        AND ii.mls_order_id IS NULL
        AND ii.damaged = false
             JOIN title ttl ON ttl.id = si.title_id
        AND ttl.active = true
             JOIN public.title_owner_title_designator_lookup totdl ON ttl.id = totdl.title_id
             JOIN locator l ON l.id = ii.locator_id
        AND l.active = true
             LEFT JOIN location_locator ll ON ll.id = l.id
        AND ll.status IN ('Shelf', 'Intake', 'Donation', 'Wholesaler')
             LEFT JOIN course_locator cl ON cl.id = l.id
    WHERE COALESCE(ll.location_id, cl.location_id) = :locationId
      AND ll.do_not_list_on_markets = false
      AND CASE
              WHEN (:designatorInclude IS NOT NULL)
                  THEN totdl.designator_id IN (:designatorInclude)
              ELSE ttl.product_code IS NOT NULL
        END
```

Comment: Look like this part is not correct. 
              ELSE ttl.product_code IS NOT NULL . Maybe you need  a parenthesis ELSE (ttl.product_code IS NOT NULL)

Comment: That did not change the outcome at all.  I ended up using a coalesce statement instead. Will add details to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by changing my IS NOT NULL check to a COALESCE

```
CASE
  WHEN **(COALESCE(:include, 0) != 0)**
    THEN totdl.designator_id IN (:include) 
ELSE ttl.product_code IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I would you, I would select just row column such

```
SELECT ttl.product_code, totdl.designator_id
FROM ...
```

I mapped this query normal to an Bean or Entity.

And an transient getter could solve your problem.